# What is the best way to compare 2 integer lists / array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

I want to compare 2 integer list for equality. I am happy to sort them in advance if that makes it easier. Here is an example of two things that i want to compare. For the below, i want the result to be true.

NOTE: there will never be any duplicates in the list (no repeating values)

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>(){1, 4,6,7};
 int[] myArray = new int[]{1, 6,7 ,4};
```

Comment: Is `{ 1, 4, 6, 7 }` equal to `{ 1, 4, 4, 6, 7 }` by your definition?

Comment: @Jason - see updated question, NO repeating values

Comment: @leora if your collection will never have duplicates then carry around `HashSet<T>`. It reveals your intent much better.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What does equality mean to you when comparing lists? Do you care that the lists are exactly the same .... the same items in the same order? Or just contain the same set of values, regardless of order.

If you actually want to verify that the lists contain the same sequence of values in the same order, you can use the `SequenceEqual()` method in LINQ:

```
bool areEqual = listA.SequenceEqual( listB );
```

If the lists are not in the same order, you can first sort them:

```
bool areEqual = listA.OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual( listB.OrderBy(x=>x) );
```

If the lists can contain duplicates, and the duplicates don't matter (with respect to equality), you can use set comparison:

```
bool setEqual = new HashSet<int>( listA ).SetEquals( listB );
```

If duplicates don't matter and you're interested in avoiding the expense of the comparison (ordering, building a hashset, etc), you could first just compare the sizes of the two collections, and only compare if they are the same.

Comment: i updated the question to be more clear in terms of what i mean by equality.  They are NOT in the same order be default but i could always sort them upfront as i mentioned in the question

Comment: @ooo: That's still somewhat ambiguous - see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you want to compare them as *sets*... in which case:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list);
if (hashSet.SetEquals(myArray))
{
    ...
}
```

Note that this will deem { 1, 2, 2, 3 } and { 1, 3, 2, 3, 1 } as being equal. Is that what you want?

There's almost certainly something built in which will do what you want, but you'll need to be exact in your description :)

EDIT: As you've stated there will be no repeated elements, this should be fine. It may be wise to document the assumption though.

Comment: in my case the numbers will always be distinct (no repeating values) but they might not be in the same order upfront.  That's why i mentioned i could sort upfront it that makes it easier

Comment: @ooo: If you know they'll be distinct, this approach should be O(n) instead of O(n log n) if you sort, so I'd probably use this. I'd document that it *does* assume distinctness though (or that you don't care about duplicates).

Comment: Why create a separate HashSet when Intersect() performs set intersection?

Comment: @manojlds: Well, that's going to create a hash set internally anyway, and it's not as clear what you're actually trying to test, IMO. (Oh, and using Intersect gives a broken result. See my comment on your answer.)