# Quicker way of comparing/matching an array of integers with LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I have the following code which compares 6 integers in 2 arrays. Is it possible to do this quicker with LINQ? Perhaps with `Enumerable.Intersect()`? I need it to compare all 6 integers in both arrays.

```
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;            
        bool jackpot = false;
        int[] randomArr = new int[6];                          
        int[] chosenArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        Random rNum = new Random();

        while (!jackpot)
        {
            i = 0;
            while (i != chosenArr.Length)
            {
                randomArr[i] = rNum.Next(1, 46);
                i += 1;
            }
            i = 0;
            while (i != chosenArr.Length)
            {
                if (!randomArr.Contains(chosenArr[i])) { break; }
                i += 1;
            }
            if (i == chosenArr.Length) { jackpot = true; }
            counter += 1;
        }
```

EDIT: I need it to match the integers in both arrays even if they are out of sequence.

Comment: Here it is exactly what you need

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766573/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-2-integer-lists-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have to be in the same order tou could use `SequenceEqual`

```
bool areEqual = chosenArr.SequenceEqual(randomArr);
```

If they can be in any order then you could use `All`

```
bool areEqual = chosenArr.All(randomArr.Contains);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I think it works assuming the numbers are equal sequentially? I need it to match the numbers even though they aren't in sequence? Sorry for miscomms, I will edit my question.

Comment: added a method to do it out of sequence