# How to Verify two Int Array and see if they are in a same order

Tags: c#

I've my list below which gives value (1,2,3)

```
int[] myInts = x.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

and i need to compare it to other list which is below,which is also (1,2,3)

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToArray();
```

Now if i do

```
bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(myInts, array);
```

it is verifying my list and giving me True . But i want to make sure that myInts array will be in a same order then only it will pass . not like if those values are equal and can be in any order.

so how would i update my above code. Please let me know .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766573/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-2-integer-lists-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: `SequenceEqual` _does_ verify that they're equal and in the same order...

Comment: You must be confusing `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` with something like `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()`

Answer (score 5):

`SequenceEqual` checks for exactly that. A sequence *is* ordered, so for two sequences to be equal, they have to have the same number of items, and the same items, in the same order.

You can look at [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,63644a881e976b52) to verify that as well:

```
public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!(e2.MoveNext() &&
                  comparer.Equals(e1.Current, e2.Current))) return false;
        }
        if (e2.MoveNext()) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The loop breaks and the method returns `false` in case both have different numbers of items, or if any item isn't equal to the item at the same place in the other sequence.